# Why will android studio not let me use "var"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project in Android Studio, and part of it would be made more simple with the use of `var`. However, every time I try to use var, I get an error: `cannot find symbol class var`. 
My code:

```java
public class Program {
    var variable = "value";
}
//note: this is not my actual code (obviously), but even this simple test doesn't work
```

Comment: `var` is java 10 feature, for android you're generally using java 7 or 8.

Comment: to use `var`, you have to switch your language to kotlin!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android is java which is older version, so you need to use strict data type for that.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio supports Java up to Version 8. var was introduced in Java 10.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by using library desugaring, check this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#kts

and add support with the following differences:

```
android { 
    [...]

    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.0") // 2.0.0 or higher required
}
```

You also need to make sure to use AGP Version 7.4.0-alpha10 or higher.